# How to declare this method in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm having trouble translating this to my swift project. Thanks in advance!!!

```
+ (void)getResortsWithState:(NSString *)state andCompletion:(void(^)(NSArray *array))complete
    {
       ....
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static func getResortsWithState(state: String, completion: ([AnyObject]) ->() )
```

or if you know type of expression in array (I assume: `Resort`):

```
static func getResortsWithState(state: String, completion: ([Resort]) ->() )
```